# Swing Menu that can be customized by user

Tags: java, swing

Is there any framework or lib out there to create a Java swing menue that can be edited by the user via drag and drop?

Added: Implementing a polished solution myself can take a lot of time. What i would like to see: display the entry while dragging, opening submenus automaticially, showing a line where the item would be placed when releasing the mouse. Actually like the windows startmenu in XP. This would take a lot of time, i am still hoping to find framework or a subclassed Jmenu with these features.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement drag and drop on most (all?) Swing components. See this [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html) to get started.

Update: based on your updated question. have a look at [JFrameBuilder](http://www.mars3000.com/) (note that its not free).

> JFrameBuilder is an easy-to-use visual Java GUI builder.
>
> JFrameBuilder provides the application GUI solution for Java developers. It enables Java developers to create sophisticated Swing GUI applications using drag-and-drop interface without spending a lot of time writing code.

Personally I find it a lot simpler to write pretty UIs in [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) (the toolkit used by Eclipse), it has more access to the underlying OS and provides a richer experience that's closer to what you're after in my opinion. Here's a [guide](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Workbench-DND/drag_drop.html) to implementing drag and drop in SWT.